# Does the tag "acts" refer to the book of Acts?

Tags: support, tags

On a [recent question I asked about a scripture in Acts](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/46207/what-does-it-mean-to-abstain-from-blood-in-the-21st-century) I had trouble coming up with appropriate tags. Another user edited the question and added tags, including [acts](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acts) (lowercase first letter). Does the tag refer to deeds or to the book of Acts? If the latter, shouldn't it be capitalized?

Comment: The appropriate tag for deeds is the "works" tag.

Answer (score 7):

You can find out what any of the tags means by clicking on "tags" in the top navigation bar and searching for it.

None of the tags are capitalized.  It's a StackExchange convention.

In this case, the Acts tag refers to:

> The fifth book of the New Testament, giving an account of the lives of
>   the apostles after Jesus' death and resurrection, and the development
>   of the early church.

[image]

Comment: In addition to the tags page, tag summaries are also shown in the auto-complete list as you type them. The clip you highlighted here is also show to anyone who types in—or even starts typing—"acts" into the tag list for their question.